# Add child pages automatically to nav menu

Tags: menus, pages

I have built a custom menu in Wordpress that contains links to posts and pages. I am adding it to my header using this line of code:

```
<?php 

wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary', 
        'depth'          => 0, 
        'menu_class'     => 'nav-menu',
    ) 
);

?>
```

My problem is, if I add a child page to the top level ones on the menu, they don't automatically appear as sublinks on the nav. I know I can create them manually each time by rebuilding the menu, but I would like to be able to just add a child page in the pages section and have it show up in the nav without having to go to the menu and build it there also, if that makes sense?

I've tried using `depth => 0`, but that didn't work. Is there a way to have child pages show up without having to build it into the custom menu?

Comment: The only way I know is when your custom menu is empty, WordPress will fill it with all existing pages. Once you start adding pages inside it, it won't continue automatically.

Comment: It looks like you've got a problem with configuring a software-component. Please contact the vendor of that component for your support options, this website here is about concrete programming questions, not how to use a vendor-specific API.

Comment: Thanks for migrating Toscho - I didn't know this forum existed.

Comment: [code for menu with sub-menu from pages and child pages](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99990/i-want-only-my-sub-pages-to-be-clickable-in-the-navbar/99996#99996).It MAY help you build your menu from child pages and child pages pragmatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

here is how:

```
/**
* auto_child_page_menu
* 
* class to add top level page menu items all child pages on the fly
* @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
*/
class auto_child_page_menu
{
    /**
     * class constructor
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @param   array $args 
     * @return  void
     */
    function __construct($args = array()){
        add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects',array($this,'on_the_fly'));
    }
    /**
     * the magic function that adds the child pages
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @param  array $items 
     * @return array 
     */
    function on_the_fly($items) {
        global $post;
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($items as $key => $i) {
            $tmp[] = $i;
            //if not page move on
            if ($i->object != 'page'){
                continue;
            }
            $page = get_post($i->object_id);
            //if not parent page move on
            if (!isset($page->post_parent) || $page->post_parent != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            $children = get_pages( array('child_of' => $i->object_id) );
            foreach ((array)$children as $c) {
                //set parent menu
                $c->menu_item_parent      = $i->ID;
                $c->object_id             = $c->ID;
                $c->object                = 'page';
                $c->type                  = 'post_type';
                $c->type_label            = 'Page';
                $c->url                   = get_permalink( $c->ID);
                $c->title                 = $c->post_title;
                $c->target                = '';
                $c->attr_title            = '';
                $c->description           = '';
                $c->classes               = array('','menu-item','menu-item-type-post_type','menu-item-object-page');
                $c->xfn                   = '';
                $c->current               = ($post->ID == $c->ID)? true: false;
                $c->current_item_ancestor = ($post->ID == $c->post_parent)? true: false; //probbably not right
                $c->current_item_parent   = ($post->ID == $c->post_parent)? true: false;
                $tmp[] = $c;
            }
        }
        return $tmp;
    }
}
new auto_child_page_menu();
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks so much for your help Bainternet! Much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for asking that but, how should I use this?
paste it in functions.php
and call it from the place where menu suppose to go?

Comment: I'm with @1GR3, how do we use this?

Comment: Yeah, simply add this to the functions.php file and press save!

Comment: Good effort, but this DOES NOT WORK! It adds ALL the child pages under the top level parent as they would be 1st level children. The 2nd and 3rd level child pages are also added under top level parent. Totally messed up my navigation.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post a clean answer because I have not enough reputation on this site. 
For interested people, I added some code to enhance this function. 

I added another condition to add class to parent list itemm, eg : 
if (count($children)>0)
$i->classes[] = 'menu-item-has-children';