# Add child pages of parent to navbar PHP

Tags: php, theme-development

I'm using a function in a custom theme which auto-populates the navigation with all the child pages of each parent. I found the code on [this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/add-child-pages-automatically-to-nav-menu)

This works well but the only thing this function doesn't do for me is order the pages with the order set in the Pages section in Wordpress. I think I need to use something like 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' somewhere in the following code, but can't for the life of me work out where?

```
/**
* auto_child_page_menu
* 
* class to add top level page menu items all child pages on the fly
* @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
*/
class auto_child_page_menu
{
    /**
     * class constructor
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @param   array $args 
     * @return  void
     */
    function __construct($args = array()){
        add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects',array($this,'on_the_fly'));
    }
    /**
     * the magic function that adds the child pages
     * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
     * @param  array $items 
     * @return array 
     */
    function on_the_fly($items) {
        global $post;
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($items as $key => $i) {
            $tmp[] = $i;
            //if not page move on
            if ($i->object != 'page'){
                continue;
            }
            $page = get_post($i->object_id);
            //if not parent page move on
            if (!isset($page->post_parent) || $page->post_parent != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            $children = get_pages( array('child_of' => $i->object_id) );
            foreach ((array)$children as $c) {
                //set parent menu
                $c->menu_item_parent      = $i->ID;
                $c->object_id             = $c->ID;
                $c->object                = 'page';
                $c->type                  = 'post_type';
                $c->type_label            = 'Page';
                $c->url                   = get_permalink( $c->ID);
                $c->title                 = $c->post_title;
                $c->target                = '';
                $c->attr_title            = '';
                $c->description           = '';
                $c->classes               = array('','menu-item','menu-item-type-post_type','menu-item-object-page');
                $c->xfn                   = '';
                $c->current               = ($post->ID == $c->ID)? true: false;
                $c->current_item_ancestor = ($post->ID == $c->post_parent)? true: false; //probbably not right
                $c->current_item_parent   = ($post->ID == $c->post_parent)? true: false;
                $tmp[] = $c;
            }
        }
        return $tmp;
    }
}
new auto_child_page_menu();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the fix for anyone who has the same issue:

```
  /**
  * auto_child_page_menu
  * 
  * class to add top level page menu items all child pages on the fly
  * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
  */
  class auto_child_page_menu
  {
      /**
       * class constructor
       * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
       * @param   array $args 
       * @return  void
       */
      function __construct($args = array()){
          add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects',array($this,'on_the_fly'));
      }
      /**
       * the magic function that adds the child pages
       * @author Ohad Raz <admin@bainternet.info>
       * @param  array $items 
       * @return array 
       */
      function on_the_fly($items) {
          global $post;
          $tmp = array();
          foreach ($items as $key => $i) {
              $tmp[] = $i;
              //if not page move on
              if ($i->object != 'page'){
                  continue;
              }
              $page = get_post($i->object_id);
              //if not parent page move on
              if (!isset($page->post_parent) || $page->post_parent != 0) {
                  continue;
              }
              $children = get_pages( array('child_of' => $i->object_id, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order') );
              foreach ((array)$children as $c) {
                  //set parent menu           
                  $c->menu_item_parent      = $i->ID;
                  $c->object_id             = $c->ID;
                  $c->object                = 'page';
                  $c->type                  = 'post_type';
                  $c->type_label            = 'Page';
                  $c->url                   = get_permalink( $c->ID);
                  $c->title                 = $c->post_title;
                  $c->target                = '';
                  $c->attr_title            = '';
                  $c->description           = '';
                  $c->classes               = array('','menu-item','menu-item-type-post_type','menu-item-object-page');
                  $c->xfn                   = '';
                  $c->current               = ($post->ID == $c->ID)? true: false;
                  $c->current_item_ancestor = ($post->ID == $c->post_parent)? true: false; //probbably not right
                  $c->current_item_parent   = ($post->ID == $c->post_parent)? true: false;
                  $tmp[] = $c;
              }

          }
          return $tmp;
      }
  }
  new auto_child_page_menu();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks @Acevandermeer

Answer (score 0):

`$items` which are passed to this function are already sorted (see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L379)). So you have to order them once again, by yourself, before `return $tmp;`

Comment: That's the bit I am struggling with