# Add child pages to submenu automatically

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, menus, hooks, sub-menu

If a new page is added under a parent page (front end), which is part of a nav menu, I want the new page to be added to the appropriate submenu automatically - without any plugin.

Reason: A custom user role has all caps to add, edit, delete posts and pages. However, this role shall not be capable to enter *Design* settings where *Menu* settings are part of. In my custom template, sub-pages simply should appear in the sub menu of their respective parents.

I understand, that I need to hook into the nav_menu render process. I guess, the first answer [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) is pretty close to a solution. However, I can't find the proper hook nor exactly how to hook in.

I fiddled around with `wp_nav_menu_items` but can't make sense of it, as the hook's callback function doesn't accept any parameters, does it?

That's my pseudo code to explain my intention:

```
function add_subpages_to_submenu($Menu){
    foreach ($Menu->Items as $Item) {
        if ($Item->hasChildren()){
            foreach ($Item->Children as $Child) {
                add_to_current_submenu($Child);
            }
        }
    }
    return $Menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_subpages_to_submenu');
```

What needs this code to look like actually?

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate? this is back-end right? if the new page is added already under a parent page, you want to the new page to be added again?

Comment: Added some more details to my question. It's all about front-end and custom template stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Good evening.

I have to make this as an answer because of missing rep.

This post might help you out :)

[Add child pages automatically to nav menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/add-child-pages-automatically-to-nav-menu)