# Add (grand)child pages automatically to nav menu

Tags: menus, pages, sub-menu

I want my submenus to be generated automatically. I've used some plugins for this, but after a while they don't get updated anymore or they have a conflict with the theme I use.

I followed this question: [Add child pages automatically to nav menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100841/add-child-pages-automatically-to-nav-menu/100850#100850?newreg=89ce6c62a19f434a998bd926a1adcb9b) and it works great, but it shows grand-children pages in the menu as if they are direct children of the parent. Can anyone help me out with displaying the grandchildren in *another* submenu under the current submenu?

Answer (score 1):

It's wise to avoid nav menus in cases like this where things may change frequently. Instead, you could look into using `wp_list_pages()` - with a custom walker if you need one to format it visually. Try `wp_list_pages()` right out of the box first and see whether you can just use CSS to style the list as desired. If not, then move on to a custom walker, which will also let you adjust the HTML.