# Remove link from Page name in navigation bar

Tags: menus, permalinks, links

I have a wordpress site and there is a navigation bar with menu and submenu.

I want to remove link attribute from menu items that have sub menu.

Is it possible? because i couldn't achieve to this by this function : `wp_list_page()`.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100014/21376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *Page Links To* plugin by Mark Jaquith. Edit top level page and in section *Page Links To* select *An alternate URL* and enter # as an URL.